# Why session.Save sends query immediately

Tags: nhibernate

What determine if `session.Save(...)` sends query to the database immediately? 
Or it defers to `commit()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mainly it depends on the chosen identity generation strategy. If it is set to something like native/identity seesion.Save() will send SQL to db immediately. That is because Save method needs to return id of the saved entity.